# How to disable keyboard shortcuts in a Powerpoint 2010 slideshow?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I would like to prevent the use of some keyboard shortcuts in a Powerpoint 2010 slideshow (like left and right arrows) while in full screen mode. Is it possible ? How can I do it ?

I was able to disable most of the other shortcuts (on-screen menu, and right click) but I cannot find a way to disable the keyboard shortcuts.

I mainly want to prevent the users from switching slides with the arrows. I was looking for an option inside powerpoint to generate an interactive game with hyperlinks for example. The arrows kind of break the purpose.

Comment: I realized that there are many [keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-use-while-delivering-a-presentation-in-powerpoint-2010-HP010336520.aspx) to intercept. Which ones do you want to keep?

Comment: @iglvzx : I mainly want to prevent the users from switching slides with the arrows. I was looking for an option inside powerpoint to generate an interactive game with hyperlinks for example. The arrows kind of break the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "Browsed at a kiosk (full screen)" option would work.

[office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-and-distribute-a-self-running-powerpoint-presentation-HA001034817.aspx) says

> Setting up a slide show to run at a kiosk allows you to control
>   whether mouse clicks anywhere on the screen advance the slide. For
>   example, if you want the slide show to be viewed at a specific pace,
>   set automatic timings and then set the slide show to run at a kiosk.
>   To give users additional control, you can add navigation, such as
>   hyperlinks or action buttons, to your slides.
>
> ```
> On the Slide Show menu, click Set Up Show.
> Under Show type, click Browsed at a kiosk (full screen).
> ```
>
> Note   If you set up a slide show to run at a kiosk, remember to also
>   add automatic timings or navigation hyperlinks or action buttons.
>   Otherwise, the slide show will show only the first slide.

I'm pretty sure it also works in Powerpoint 2007 and 2010 (even though they aren't mentioned on that page).

Comment: Yes. The **Kiosk** feature is also in PowerPoint [2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-a-self-running-presentation-HA001234200.aspx) and [2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/create-a-self-running-presentation-HA010338348.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

### Note:

Before the design of the slideshow was brought up, my answer would have worked. Now, I think that *@TheElectricMuffin*'s answer is the best for *@Matthieu*. I'm leaving my answer up for those who may be looking for a way to disable only the `Next|Previous` keyboard shortcuts.

---

This can be done using [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com):

```
#IfWinActive, PowerPoint Slide Show

    ;disable 'Next'
    n::
    Enter::
    PgDn::
    Right::
    Down::
    Space::
    
    ;disable 'Previous'
    p::
    PgUp::
    Left::
    Up::
    BackSpace::
    
#IfWinActive
```